# Getting specific XML Node from XmlWriter C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I would like to know if there is any chance of getting specific XML node from XmlWriter.

I've got a method, which exports employees to XML document and has a structure, something like:

```
<header> 
<agency>
...
<employees>
 <employee>
  ....
 </employee>
 <empolyee>
  ...
 </employee>
</employees>
...
```

in for cycle in this method each employee is created and filled with elements. The whole method for exporting this XML has already been written.

Now, at the end of the loop, I would like to create a string, which contains the node of the employee, but I don't know, how to do it with the writer which is filled with the data in the loop.

I've tried to search for some solution, but I didn't find anything good for my case. I've considered something like MemoryStream, but I think that you need to pass the stream while you are creating the XmlWriter, which in my case firstly writes the header node etc.

Could you please help me with this? I don't want to create another Writer or Reader and write the nodes twice. At first, I would like to find some better solution.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I'm pasting some of the code as you want:

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = ("\t");
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filenameXml, settings);

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("message");
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("data");

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("header");
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("agency", agencyNumber);
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("employees");

        //Loading of employees from DB and some other work

        for (int i = 0; i < employeesDs.RowCount(); i++)
        {                 
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("employee");

            //A lot of work - xmlWriter.WriteElementString so many times or WriteStartElement (address, numbers, dates etc)

            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();   // employee

            //HERE I would like to add new method which stores whole Employee element created in this iteration i to the string
            //After that I need to store this string to DB to VARCHAR MAX, but I don't know how to get the string of the Employee
            //from the writer in this part of the code 
        }

        //another work - closing and flushing xmlwriter, disposing etc and exporting whole xml document
```

Comment: What do you mean by `at the end of the loop`? After the loop has finished? Or as the last thing to happen in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Could you append your sample code to give better insight for the readers of this question?

Comment: Last thing to happen. I need to copy the structure of <employee> element which is filled (xmlWriter.WriteElementString used many times for the writer, which records the whole export even with the header etc - so whole structure of xml) in the loop and I want to pull out at the end of the loop only the employee corresponding to the iteration of the loop.

Comment: It would help enormously if you could put your current code into the question so we have some idea of what we're dealing with. Also, it will be very hard to answer your question without knowing your required result. Where should this string go? What should it contain?

Comment: Alternatively, if all you want to do is get a textual representation of **every** `employee` element, why not use LINQ to XML to locate each `employee` element in the XML document after you've created and turn them into strings?

Comment: Assuming you have your XML loaded into an XDocument, you could do this: `xDocument.Descendants("employee").Select(x => x.ToString())` to get an enumerable of strings of each `employee` element.

Comment: I've added new edit with the code example. In the method xmlWriter writes to the XML file directly - maybe I gave the information to you badly - sorry.